# Why does this service refuse to start on Windows server 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003, service

We have a Windows 2003 server with Cebos MQ1 (ver. 7 and ver. GRI) products installed that have been operational for years. After installing [Microsoft 2010 C++ Redistributable package](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555) needed for other development, the MQ1 GRI service now fails to start.

Event logs showed that two additional updates (.NET4 and the 2010 C++ Redistributable SP2) where installed by the redistributable as well. As soon as we discovered the MQ1 service was not starting properly, we removed these three installed packages. However the service still does not start; the dialog that pops up states 'The service started then stopped. '.

Event logs when we attempt to start the service show nothing; IE: No errors, crashes, failures, or other information related to this service. Executing the MQ1Serv.exe directly specifies an issue of '[Missing command line operation, must specify install, uninstall and company abbreviation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nB44D.png).' `sc query MQ1Service(GRI)` shows a clean exit for the Win32ExitCode of `0x0`. Attempting to reinstall the client or server software gives an error of '[The procedure entry point ReInitializeCriticalSection could not be located in the dynamic link library KERNEL32.dll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEzDu.png).' at the 'Registering Libraries' stage.

At this point, further research has stated that the required function is in URL.dll and to verify the library is not corrupted. Running an `sfc /scannow` on the server has replaced a few DLLS; including the URL.DLL to versions from 2005. This actually broke other applications which required a reinstall (one of them being IE 7). After reinstall and updates, url.dll version is 7.0.5730.13 (2009) and Kernel32.dll is version 5.2.3790.4480 (2009).  The MQ1 GRI service still will not start, specifying the same error as previous 'Service started then stopped'. Running a disassembler on Kernel32.dll and Url.dll show no functions named `ReinitializeCriticalSection`.

Attempting the reinstall of the MQ1 client and server as well as starting the service again, fails once more. However, setting the compatibility mode on the MQ1 client install exe to 'Windows 95' actually gets the program to install. Setting the compatibility mode on the MQ1 server service does not enable it to start.

I have been researching this problem for nearly a week and besides the advice to scan and replace url.dll, have come to no successful conclusions. This service was operational prior to the 2010 C++ install, without any additional parameters or settings. After removing the C++ install and all servicepacks/updates it installed silently, still does not correct the issue of the MQ1 GRI service not starting.

**Q**: Has anyone else run into this or similar issue while attempting to get a service initialized? What have I overlooked or what else can I try in order to get this service started??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though the reinstall was throwing errors related to 'ReInitializeCriticalSection' this error of the service not starting had nothing to do with the Kernel32.dll. A misconfiguration in the MQ1ServerSettings.ini (rootpath attribute) was overwritten. Correcting the location to this path and reinstalling the MQ1Service allowed it to start up successfully as expected.